# How to set z-index in my scenario using css?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

```html
<html>

<head>       
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="DateBetween">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Date From
        <input type="text" ID="txtDateFrom" class="form-control" runat="server" />
        <script type="text/ecmascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#txtDateFrom").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showAnim: "fold",
                    yearRange: "2013:2017"
                });
                $("#txtDateFrom").focus(function () {
                    $("#datepick").datepicker("show");
                });
                $("#txtDateFrom").focus();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    Date To
        <input type="text" ID="txtDateTo" class="form-control" runat="server" >
        <script type="text/ecmascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtDateTo").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showAnim: "fold",
                yearRange: "2013:2017"
             });
            $("#txtDateTo").focus(function () {
                $("#datepick").datepicker("show");
            });
            $("#txtDateTo").focus();
        });
        </script>
    </div>
 </div>
```

> UPDATE
>
> **I am using jquery-3.1.1**. when I add Jquery-3.1.1 cdn on Runsnippet, it's not working. So I add **jquery-1.12.4.js** on **Snippet**
>
> In my case, at first time it is showing perfectly. But and rest of the time when user click on the text box it showing like snippet output

I have a date picker calendar. When user click the text box, the date picker calendar will appear.

> The problem is at first time when user click the text box, it's showing datepicker completely without any problem like below
>   [image: correct display]
>
> when I click the muse in outside of the text box and again try to click on the ext box, it's not appearing completely. It's showing like below

[image: wrong display]

Here is the code on browser which is displaying for date picker

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" 
    class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" 
    style="position: absolute; 
           top: 470px; left: 618.25px; 
           z-index: 1; margin: 0px; 
           height: 231.422px; clip: rect(0px 238px 15px 0px); 
           display: block;">
```

Please give me the solution with proper reason

Thanks

Comment: Can you write your code in a snippet here ?

Comment: @nimish ok please hold on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use showAnim: "fold" as it will create an issue everytime. I have tried different js for datepicker and found an issue with this option (showAnim: "fold").

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#txtDateFrom').datepicker();
$('#txtDateFrom').focus(function(){
    $('#txtDateFrom').datepicker('show');
});
$('#txtDateTo').datepicker();
$('#txtDateTo').focus(function(){
    $('#txtDateTo').datepicker('show');
});
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,                
  yearRange: "2013:2017"       
});

});
```

```css
.col-lg-3{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="DateBetween">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        Date From
        <input type="text" id="txtDateFrom" class="form-control" runat="server" />
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    Date To
        <input type="text" id="txtDateTo" class="form-control" runat="server" >       
    </div>
 </div>
```